# Null Pointer Exception error. Cant understand

Tags: nullpointerexception

```
public class multi {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[][]= new int[2][];
    arr[0]= new int[1];
    arr[0]= new int[2];
    int a,b,c=5;

    for(a=0;a<2;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<a+1;b++)
        {
            arr[a][b]=c;
            c++;
        }
    }
    for(a=0;a<2;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<=a;b++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[a][b]);

        }
    }

}
}
```

**ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at multi.main(multi.java:14)**
I do not understand what's my mistake and why this error is showing up. I am a beginner and have just started learning java. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
arr[0]= new int[1];
arr[0]= new int[2];
```

to

```
arr[0]= new int[1];
arr[1]= new int[2];
```